# How to return an image as output of c++ function which is used in python code>

Tags: opencv, shared-libraries, ctypes, mat

I wrote a python code which is for some image processing purposes.
for some performance reasons, I wrote a c++ function which accept two image as it's arguments and just blending them and return the result image. I test c++ function individually and then use it in my python code using ctypes. after compile c++ code as shared library, I run my python code. but it gives some error like this:

```
Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 476741369964 bytes)
Failed to allocate 476741369964 bytes in function OutOfMemoryError
```

while size of my images is less than 2 megabyte.

can anyone help me how to solve this problem?

this is declaration of my c++ function:

```
extern "C" Mat blend(Mat img1, Mat img2)
```

this is my c++ function:

```
extern "C" Mat watermark2(Mat source_img, Mat logo)
{

        double alpha = 0.5;

        int width = logo.size().width;
        int height = logo.size().height;
        int x_pos = rand() % (source_img.size().width - width - 10) + 10;
        int y_pos = rand() % (source_img.size().height - height - 10) + 10;

        cv::Rect pos = cv::Rect(x_pos, y_pos, width, height);
        addWeighted(source_img(pos), alpha, logo, 1 - alpha, 0.0, source_img(pos));

        return source_img;
}
```

and in my django project, insdie views.py, call c++ function and use returned image in order to response in as HttpResponse.

```
watermarked_image = c_obj.watermark(local_path, logo_path)

return HttpResponse(cv2.imencode('.jpg', watermarked_image)[1].tobytes(), content_type="image/png")
```

Comment: Why would someone try to allocate *450GB*? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it seems in my python code, where i call c++ function, it can't accept output of my c++ code as a mat object. maybe a convert is required in order to use mat object which returned from c++ code.